# Unable to obtain archiver for extension 'tgz'

Tags: macos, maven-assembly-plugin

I am seeing below error while executing TestNG test cases in Eclipse on my Mac. No idea how to resolve it.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (make-assembly) on project abc-services-tests: Failed to create assembly: Unable to obtain archiver for extension 'tgz' -> [Help 1]
```

Here is the code from `pom.xml`:

```xml
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.xyz.openapi.RunTestNG</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>

                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Can some one please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue by doing maven clean install from terminal. somehow maven clean install from eclipse didn't work.